# How speed up reading data from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, teradata

The time costs of reading data from S3  is much more than write data to S3.

Same data content,

read SQL:

```
INSERT INTO RiverFlowPerm_csv
SELECT
payload..datetime
,payload..site_no
,Cast (payload..Flow AS FLOAT)
,Cast (payload..Velocity AS FLOAT)
,Cast (payload..GageHeight AS FLOAT)
,Cast (payload..Temp AS FLOAT)
FROM riverflow_csv;
```

read RESULT:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsSsO.jpg

write SQL :

```
SELECT ObjectSize, RecordCount
FROM WRITE_NOS_FM (
 ON  ( SELECT * FROM RiverFlowPerm_csv )
  PARTITION BY SiteNo ORDER BY SiteNo
 USING
  LOCATION('/s3/bigdXXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/RiverFlowPerm/')
  STOREDAS('PARQUET')
  NAMING('DISCRETE')
  INCLUDE_ORDERING('TRUE')
  MAXOBJECTSIZE('4MB')
) AS d
ORDER BY AmpId;
```

write RESULT : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3isI0.jpg

schema : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbfM6.jpg

How to speed up reading data from S3 ??? What can I do ?

---

### 2021/5/26

In above case,
I create a foreign table like this (JUST COPY FROM TERA DATA DOC)，  I think may be something wrong with my SQL, any advice? 2048  or 6400 too large? how to modify it to a reasonable range(Location and Payload )?

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE riverflow_csv
, EXTERNAL SECURITY DEFINER TRUSTED DefAuth
( 
   Location VARCHAR(2048) CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC,
   Payload DATASET INLINE LENGTH 64000 STORAGE FORMAT CSV
)
USING (LOCATION('/s3/bigdatalakedemo.s3.amazonaws.com/CSVDATA/'));
```

the csv file format is like this about 10MB (in S3 Server)

```
Temp,Flow,site_no,datetime,Conductance,Precipitation,GageHeight
11.0,16200,09380000,2018-06-27 00:00,669,0.00,9.97
10.9,16000,09380000,2018-06-27 00:15,668,0.00,9.93
10.9,15700,09380000,2018-06-27 00:30,668,0.00,9.88
10.8,15400,09380000,2018-06-27 00:45,672,0.00,9.82
10.8,15100,09380000,2018-06-27 01:00,672,0.00,9.77
10.8,14700,09380000,2018-06-27 01:15,672,0.00,9.68
10.7,14300,09380000,2018-06-27 01:30,673,0.00,9.61
10.7,13900,09380000,2018-06-27 01:45,672,0.00,9.53
10.7,13600,09380000,2018-06-27 02:00,671,0.00,9.46
10.6,13200,09380000,2018-06-27 02:15,672,0.00,9.38
11.0,16200,09380000,2018-06-27 00:00,669,0.00,9.97
10.9,16000,09380000,2018-06-27 00:15,668,0.00,9.93
10.9,15700,09380000,2018-06-27 00:30,668,0.00,9.88
10.8,15400,09380000,2018-06-27 00:45,672,0.00,9.82
10.8,15100,09380000,2018-06-27 01:00,672,0.00,9.77
10.8,14700,09380000,2018-06-27 01:15,672,0.00,9.68
10.7,14300,09380000,2018-06-27 01:30,673,0.00,9.61
10.7,13900,09380000,2018-06-27 01:45,672,0.00,9.53
10.7,14300,09380000,2018-06-27 01:30,673,0.00,9.61
```

Can I use something like this sql to get schema info，and use it to make the FOREIGN TABLE riverflow_csv size more reasonable? how to do it?
(This is a PARQUET example )

```
SELECT ParquetColumnName,TDColumnType
FROM READ_NOS_FM (
USING
STOREDAS('PARQUET')
FULLSCAN('TRUE')
RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_PARQUET_SCHEMA')
LOCATION('/s3/bXXXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com/PARQUETDATA/)
) AS D;
```

change above sql  varchar size get a  strange  error message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILceM.jpg

Comment: Please Edit your question to include details of how you are using S3. For example, it appears that you are running Terradata? How is it associated with S3? Is everything running in the AWS Cloud, or are some things outside of AWS? More information, please!

Comment: I  think the major problem  is  in Tera data.  I  use a Tera Data Express  VM on  local computer  to read data from S3.  The time costs of reading data from S3 is much more than write data to S3.

Comment: If you are connecting to S3 across the Internet, then it comes down to the speed and latency of your Internet connection. If you were to run the same software from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 bucket, the performance would be significantly better.

Comment: https://docs.teradata.com/r/EK02hHM782ghx133Qdd67g/T_XbGHgJhi55knt6uQbxww  this is what I reference.